# Selecionar um elemento por atributo no Javascript sem Jquery

Tags: javascript

Como selecionar um elemento por algum atributo tipo (type, for, value) como se faz no jQuery ex: [type=text]?

Queria fazer uma função pra pular campos em um formulário automático...queria fazer tipo assim, pegar o tabindex do elemento atual e fazer o elemento tabindex + 1 ganha focus().

Segue o script para pular campos ao serem preenchidos por completo com auxilio do Sérgio:

```js
function pulacampo(id){
 var campo = document.getElementById(id);
 var proximo = campo.tabIndex +  1; 
 var proximoElemento = document.querySelector("[tabindex='" + proximo + "']");
   
   if (campo.value.length == campo.maxLength){
    proximoElemento.focus(); 
   
   
  }
 
}
```

Precisa só definir os tabindex dos campos e inserir a função no keypress/down/up

Comment: É igual ao jQeury mas usando o `querySelector`. Testa `document.querySelector('[type="text"]');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes usar o [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) para [seletores CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors).

Por exemplo `var tres = document.querySelector('[tabindex="3"]');`

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/x8mbbx43/

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente, vou deixar a função para quem precisar